# Analytical Chemistry Textbook Recommendation

Tags: electrochemistry, equilibrium, analytical-chemistry, books

Could anyone recommend a good book for self-learning that provide a clear, step by step guide on solving such chemical equilibria questions.

**It should cover the following topics:** weak acid and strong base titration, buffers, redox reactions, electrochemical reactions, complexation reactions, potentiometric titrations.

Preferably, I would like it if the textbook also provide work solutions to the practice questions it gives. I heard that **Fundamentals of Analytical Chemistry** by Skoog is good and covers the topics that I have listed above but I don't think it provides any worked solutions to its questions.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentals of Analytical Chemistry is a fine book and it does have an student solution.

Comment: Stack exchange doesn't encourage _link-only_ answers. Please elaborate your opinion behind citing this.